# Overrides for specific element of a master page

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

Is there a way to allow overrides for a specific element on a master page? Right now it seems I can only 'Override All Master Page Items' from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+`click` the item(s) you want to override on the page you want them overridden on. This will unlock them from  the master page and make them in-page elements.

If you want to override all master pages items on several pages, simply highlight the pages in the **Pages Panel** and choose `Override All Master Page Items` from thePages Panel menu. However, this will only work for *all* master items. You can't cherry pick which master items get overridden with this method.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to achieve this for all the pages the master page has been applied to

Comment: So you no longer want the master page item on the master pages? I think that will encompass a lot of copy/pasting. Copy from master, delete, then paste in place on every page you need the object. Or go through all pages command-shift-clicking the object, then go delete it from the master page.

Comment: It's a text box. I just want to 'unlock' all the instances of this text box at once to be able to write inside them

Comment: I don't think there's an easy method other than my comment above. Perhaps someone else will have a good method.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+CLICK does not unlock the items. It deletes them for some reason. It does not push them to another layer or unlock them. It straight up deletes them.

Comment: That is simply not true. If that's happening on *your* system, then it's an issue on *your* system.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question now and thought it was interesting.
Here is a little script that gets the job done.

Just save it as a .jsx in your script folder, select an object on a master page and run the script with a double click.

```
//DESCRIPTION:Overrides a selected item of the master page in the entire document.
#target InDesign

if(! (app.selection.length == 1) ){
    alert("Error\rSelect exactly one item on a master page and try again.");
    exit();
    }

var sel = app.selection[0];
var masterSpread = sel.parentPage.parent;

if(! (masterSpread.constructor.name == "MasterSpread") ){
    alert("Error\rThe selected item is not on a master page. Select an item on a master page and try again.");
    exit();
    }

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var side = sel.parentPage.side;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.pages.length; i++){
    var page = doc.pages[i];
    if(page.side == side && page.appliedMaster == masterSpread){
        sel.override(page);
        }
    }
```

This should work in most cases, however it will not work in more complicated setups with spreads that contain more than 2 pages etc.