# Override a master page style

Tags: adobe-indesign

My master page has a stroke at the top which is supposed to be shared across all pages. The stroke has a style assigned defining its appearance.

[image: master page top bar shared across all other pages]

Lets say the idea is to have the stroke's colour change depending on the section you're in. It's pretty common in magazines where, say, movies section would be themed red, and sports would be in green.

Is there an easy way to override the colour only? I'd like to keep the stroke size, position, pattern etc. the same.

I know [there are master page *elements* overrides](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37917/overrides-for-specific-element-of-a-master-page), but I guess this is different since it involves a style override?

Comment: Most of the advice I'm finding [involves pulling an element from the master page and making it a local element](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A41Y2MhDIg4). I actually want that stoke to remain a master page item, I just want it adjusted locally in one small aspect.

Comment: You need multiple master pages, one for each situation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there are master page items and local page items. You can't mix the edit ability without breaking the master page overrides. I don't think there's any such thing as "adjust locally but retain master".

Just create a second master page for color variations.

You can apply a master page to another master, then override a single element on the new master.

- `Master A` applied to `Master B`
- override bar on `Master B` and change it's color
- Apply `Master B` to new page

Everything but the overrides on `Master B` will stay the same as `Master A`.

So... if you edit something other than the bar on `Master A`, like the page number, that will be applied to `Master B` and subsequently any pages with `Master A` **AND** `Master B` applied to them.